# Select and count the same records

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

In my Stored Procedure, I have two queries:

Here rec_count is out parameter and cursor_name is in out parameter.

```
open cursor_name for
select <col list> from <table1 join table2 inner join...> on <join conditions> where <conditions>;

select count(*) into rec_count from <table1 join table2 inner join...> on <join conditions> where <conditions>;
```

- Is there a way I can do the select and count together as I am providing the same join conditions and where clause again?
- Will this affect performance or SQL Optimizer will optimize these two queries?

Comment: Depending on your real problem and usage context (that you do not describe) other possible PL/SQL solutions are 1) [bulk collect](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/tuning.htm#LNPLS891) and 2) [rowcount cursor attribute](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/static.htm#LNPLS00603). However the proposed `count over`-solution is a good one too.

Answer (score 1):

You could do the analytic count over the entire data set like this -

```
OPEN cursor_name for
   SELECT <col_list> , 
          count(*) over () as cnt 
   from <tables> <join conditions> <where clauses>;
```

That way the cursor would have a column with the count of all rows in each row.

Answer (score 1):

There are bigger issues than you are thinking to be here.

> What if another session commits a transaction meanwhile between you open the cursor and select count? Obviously, the **count** of the rows that of the **cursor** will not match with your select **count(*)** query.

**Oracle doesn't know the count of rows, until the last row is fetched.**

If you want an exact count of rows, then I would insist an `analytic count(*) over()` in your existing cursor query.

Comment: will count(*) over () be the same as my approach performance wise?

Comment: In your case you are querying the tables twice, once with the cursor next with select count. Having analytic count over() in the cursor query will give you the count in the same query. And it will also be correct.